# Is there any software to regularize British vs. American spelling in a text?

Tags: writing-style, software, language, grammar

This is a minor but ongoing annoyance that takes up more time than I would like, and I am wondering if anybody knows of a solution.  I often write papers with foreign collaborators, and we tend to end up with a mixture of British and American spellings of words in our text.  We know it's a problem, and often agree on which to use ahead of time, but it's so ingrained one often doesn't even realize when you've made a mistake.  Thus, in the final proofing stage, somebody has to go through and manually regularize the spelling, which is really boring and time-consuming.

My question is this: does anybody know of software that can help automate this process?  It feels to me like it should exist, but I don't know of any...

Comment: What’s wrong with using a spellchecker?

Comment: This would be a great semester-long software assignment for undergrad computer science majors if nothing has been made yet! Edit: [This](http://www.us2uk.eu/) would probably do lightweight work. A heavyweight application would use something like Java or .NET.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft spell check is okay at forcing American English, but forcing British English is a little problematic. For example, MS Word thinks, correctly so, that both localize and localise are correct in British English.

Comment: @StrongBad: Interesting, any spellchecker I have used in the last years (which does not include Word) corrects *localize* to *localise* (and similar) for British English.

Comment: I tend to edit mostly in Emacs, which generally happily accepts both spellings.

Comment: Emacs doesn't actually have its own spell checker AFAIK; rather it uses one of a variety of external spell checkers.  Two that I know of are `ispell` and `aspell`.  Each of those should have both British and American dictionaries, and you may be able check which one (or both) is actually being used.  But I think that may become off topic for this site.

Comment: https://github.com/compassghost/EnglishBridge/ is the initial run I had. It is bare-bones. Takes a dictionary in a CSV, digests it, and then goes through a .docx and replaces anything it finds with the opposite. I have to read some more documentation, but I've made it open source so people can play with it if they want. Don't expect anything pretty in the source yet.

Comment: don't assume the differences between the two forms are limited to spelling. there are grammar and word sense variations too, probably much harder to resolve.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft my point was that localize with a z is a valid spelling in British English.

Comment: I wonder if this would be a better fit at software recs.se?

Comment: @StrongBad I've no objection to migration since it certainly hasn't gotten any good answer here...

Comment: @jakebeal I edited your question for two reasons: 1) to edit its title and the tags; 2) to bring it in the front page as it has no posted answer for a long time. I hope this may help you find your answer.

Comment: "We know it's a problem" -- Is it? As they say, "the official language of science is broken English", so this seems a very minor issue to me, compared to what I read in many other papers. (Disclaimer: I am fluent in broken English myself, so I might miss many language subtleties.)

Comment: Can't migrate this anymore. More than 60 days have passed.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think that it is a problem, because I feel that native English speakers like myself are typically held (quite reasonably) to a significantly higher standard.

Comment: I voted to close as it seems off topic to academia -- really any collaborative environment has this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There is an add-in for Microsoft Word called [myWriterTools](http://www.mywritertools.com/Products_mwt.asp) that will convert US to UK English and vice-versa. It also highlights changes so you can double-check. It isn't free however.

Alternatively you could use CTRL + A to select all your text in the existing document and set the proofing language to your desired version of English. This will then show the majority of errors as incorrect spelling (be wary of words such as license and licence though which may be used in different contexts) in Word.

Compass in a comment has mentioned an online converter [US2UK](http://www.us2uk.eu/) that may be useful for shorter documents.

I have searched for a LaTeX equivalent but it would appear one does not exist currently.